# Binomial coefficients algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, substitution

I am trying to prove 
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k-1}\frac{n-k+2}{k}$$ by using the following four equations: 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n + 1}{k} & = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}\\
\binom{n + 1}{k - 1} & = \binom{n}{k - 1} + \binom{n}{k - 2}\\
\binom{n}{k} & = \binom{n}{k - 1}\frac{n - k + 1}{k}\\
\binom{n}{k - 1} & = \binom{n}{k - 2}\frac{n - k + 2}{k - 1}
\end{align*}
Assume the above equations are true and valid to use.

Answer (score 0):

If in your last relation
$$\binom{n}{k - 1} = \binom{n}{k - 2}\frac{n - k + 2}{k - 1}$$
you substitute $n$ with $n+1$ and $k$ with $k+1$, then you get the desired relation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the third equation, replacing $n$ by $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners to these kinds of proofs, sometimes it is just easier renaming the variables. For example:

I am trying to prove
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k-1}\frac{n-k+2}{k}$$
Assuming that the following is true
$$\binom{r}{s}=\binom{r}{s-1}\frac{r-s+1}{s}$$
Notice that this is just your third identity, expressed in $r,s$ instead of $n,k$. Now it's just a simple matter of replacing $r$ with $n+1$ and $s$ with $k$.